# Can I trust MQTT when phone in power safe mode

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I have simple Paho MQTT Android client application:

```
public class PahoExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

    final String serverUri = "ssl://myserver:8887";

    String clientId = "ExampleAndroidClient";
    final String subscriptionTopic = "aaa/";
    final String publishTopic = "exampleAndroidPublishTopic";






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Timber.plant(new  Timber.DebugTree());
        Timber.plant(new FileLoggingTree(this));
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("starting");


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverUri, clientId);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

                if (reconnect) {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                    // Because Clean Session is true, we need to re-subscribe
                    subscribeToTopic();
                } else {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Connected to: " + serverURI);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("The Connection was lost.");

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Incoming message: " + new String(message.getPayload()));
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

            }
        });

        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);

        mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(300);
        mqttConnectOptions.setUserName("a");
        mqttConnectOptions.setPassword("a".toCharArray());


        try {
            mqttConnectOptions.setSocketFactory(SocketFactoryMQ.getSocketFactory(this,""));
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            Timber.e ( e);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).e ( e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).e ( e);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).e ( e);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).e ( e);
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).e ( e);
        }



        try {
            //addToHistory("Connecting to " + serverUri);
            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                    mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                    subscribeToTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
                }
            });


        } catch (MqttException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void subscribeToTopic(){
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Subscribed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Failed to subscribe");
                }
            });


            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, new IMqttMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                    // message Arrived!
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Message: " + topic + " : " + new String(message.getPayload()));
                    sendNotification(topic,new String(message.getPayload()));
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException ex){
            System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public void sendNotification(String title, String message) {

        ... 

    }


}
```

Everything works fine when phone is connected to charger or active. My application miss 
MQTT messages when phone is disconnected from charger and is closed (I call it power safe mode). In this situation after some time phone starts to miss MQTT messages. According to log taken from phone we can see that messages appear when phone is waked up:

```
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:41:27:776 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 2
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:41:49:537 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 3
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:44:26:972 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 2
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:44:47:913 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 3
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:45:20:876 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 4
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:46:01:322 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 5
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:46:52:873 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 6
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:47:09:993 pm  The Connection was lost.
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:54:44:263 pm  Reconnected to : ssl://myserver:8887
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:54:44:357 pm  Subscribed!
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:54:48:196 pm  MainActivity.onStart
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:55:28:465 pm  MainActivity.onStop
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:55:33:080 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 12
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:57:35:070 pm  Message:  aaa/ : 13
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 02:58:30:264 pm  The Connection was lost.
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 03:02:54:001 pm  Reconnected to : ssl://myserver:8887
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 03:02:54:103 pm  Subscribed!
```

Messages 7-11 just not reached my device. How to solve this problem?

UPD

After change `QOS 0` to `QOS 1` I got all messages. Messages starting from 10 came at the same time after some delay. From first glance 5 min. delay is not relevant, but I'm not sure how big delay it might be. For example 30 min. delay is not appropriate.

```
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:20:54:411 pm  Message: aaa/ : 2
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:21:16:221 pm  Message: aaa/ : 3
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:21:48:173 pm  Message: aaa/ : 4
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:22:29:642 pm  Message: aaa/ : 5
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:23:21:571 pm  Message: aaa/ : 6
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:24:23:327 pm  Message: aaa/ : 7
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:25:34:278 pm  Message: aaa/ : 8
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:26:56:309 pm  Message: aaa/ : 9
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:27:16:408 pm  The Connection was lost.
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:27:667 pm  MainActivity.onStart
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:37:320 pm  Reconnected to : ssl://myserver:8887
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:37:390 pm  Message: aaa/ : 10
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:37:442 pm  Subscribed!
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:37:450 pm  Message: aaa/ : 11
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:37:498 pm  Message: aaa/ : 12
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:32:38:084 pm  MainActivity.onStop
Thu Feb 20 2020 at 06:34:02:431 pm  Message: aaa/ : 13
```

Comment: i try it wil rabbit mq and it works fine , try to establish you service , it will handle all the scenarios

Comment: @B.mansouri This has nothing to do with the broker, all brokers will behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have subscribed to the topic at QOS 0 which is "fire and forget", no effort will be made to make sure the message is actually delivered.

```
mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, new IMqttMessageListener() {...
```

If you want assured delivery you need to use QOS 1 (At least once) or QOS 2 (Once and only once)

```
mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 1, new IMqttMessageListener() {...
```

Comment: This partly helped! I got all messages, but still have delay. More details in UPD in message body.

Comment: Any delay will need down to how long it takes to reconnect. All missed messages will be delivered as soon as you reconnect (assuming same clientid and cleansession is set to false)

Comment: If you need missed messages to time out then you need to use MQTTv5 which includes a message TTL field

Comment: I got all my messages that came after delay, but delay is too big

Comment: Right, and as I said, the delay is purely down to how long it took the app to reconnect, the broker will deliver those waiting messages as soon as the client reconnects.