# Prevent phone from sleep while communicating to MQTT server

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I'm [getting message reception delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320695/can-i-trust-mqtt-when-phone-in-power-safe-mode/60322661#60322661) when my phone gets to sleep mode. I was trying to prevent phone from getting to sleep mode by

Add line to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And adding code below on main activity start:

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
...

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My:Application");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

But after some time phone gets into sleep mode as usual. What I do wrong?

What is the best way to prevent phone from getting to sleep mode or wake up for some intervals to check new messages on MQTT server?

Comment: Is a foreground service running during the time you hold the `WakeLock`?

Comment: No, I just placed these several lines of code in MainActivity and manifest. No any special foreground service was created.

Comment: I think you need that on later versions of Android. I believe there is a written reference on that, but I'd have a great deal of trouble finding it.

Comment: Also, how do you ensure your `WakeLock` stays in scope? An `Activity` is likely to be killed after the screen turns off.

Comment: I suppose best place to place `wakeLock` is foreground service class and acquire it in on it's `onCreate`